# I cant change the value with setState in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm learning react native and I've been trying to solve this issue for last 3 days.

I'm using EXPO, The buttons does not change the value in `const [isStarted, setIsStarted] = useState(false)`

The buttons titles are: "pause" and "start"

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Button,Alert } from 'react-native';
import { colors } from '../../utils/colors';
import { spacing } from '../../utils/sizes';
import { Countdown } from '../../components/Countdown';
import { RoundedButton } from '../../components/RoundedButton';
import {ProgressBar} from 'react-native-paper';

export const Timer = ({ focusSubject }) => {
  const [isStarted, setIsStarted] = useState(false);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.countdown}>
        <Countdown isPaused={!isStarted}/>
      </View>
      <View styles={{ paddingTop: spacing.xxl }}>
        <Text style={styles.title}> Focusing on: </Text>
        <Text style={styles.task}> {focusSubject} </Text>
      </View>

    <View style= {styles.buttonWrapper}>
    {isStarted ? (
      **<RoundedButton title="pause" onPress={() => setIsStarted(false)} />**
    ) : (
      **<RoundedButton title="start" onPress={() => setIsStarted(true)} />**
    
    )}
    </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  title: {
    color: colors.white,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  task: {
    color: colors.white,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  countdown: {
    flex: 0.5,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  buttonWrapper: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 0.3,
    padding: 15,
    justifyContent: 'center',

  },
});
```

Comment: My concerns are with that imported component you've used. Can you please confirm if you have any method named onPress defined on that RoundedButton component? Maybe it's an onClick on that component, not sure.

Comment: Check if onPress is being called or not. Also, post the code for RoundedButton

Comment: Please update the code of RoundedButton code can be simplify much more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a prop name to RoundedButton component and inside of that you need to call onPress

for ex:

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Button,Alert } from 'react-native';
import { colors } from '../../utils/colors';
import { spacing } from '../../utils/sizes';
import { Countdown } from '../../components/Countdown';
import { RoundedButton } from '../../components/RoundedButton';
import {ProgressBar} from 'react-native-paper';

export const Timer = ({ focusSubject }) => {
  const [isStarted, setIsStarted] = useState(false);
  const onButtonPress = () => {
     setIsStarted(!isStarted)
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.countdown}>
        <Countdown isPaused={!isStarted}/>
      </View>
      <View styles={{ paddingTop: spacing.xxl }}>
        <Text style={styles.title}> Focusing on: </Text>
        <Text style={styles.task}> {focusSubject} </Text>
      </View>

    <View style= {styles.buttonWrapper}>
      <RoundedButton title={isStarted ? "pause" : "start"} onButtonHandler={onButtonPress} />
    </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  title: {
    color: colors.white,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  task: {
    color: colors.white,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  countdown: {
    flex: 0.5,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  buttonWrapper: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 0.3,
    padding: 15,
    justifyContent: 'center',

  },
});
```

Here I added a button handler as a prop into RoundedButton, now inside RoundedButton call `onPress={onButtonHandler}` in the touchable event.

If you are still facing trouble please share update RoundedButton component code

Comment: thanks! yes the problem was in RoundedButton.js!  this was missing "onPress={props.onPress}", inside TouchableOpacity :D